# Extract previous month from current date using timeDate library

Tags: r, timedate

I'm using the `timeDate` library instead of `lubridate` because it appears easier to determine when certain stock markets are open.

Given the current date, how do I extract the previous month in numeric form?

So if the current date is: "2022-12-09

prev_month = 11

And if the current date is: "2023-01-03"

prev_month = 12

```
library("timeDate")
current_date <- as.timeDate(Sys.Date())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(timeDate)
if (match(months(dt), month.name) == 1) 12  else  match(months(dt), month.name) - 1
```

month.name is an object in base R containing the full month names. By using match, you can convert between the month names and month numbers.

As months cycle from 1 to 12, when you step back from 1, you need to go to 12, not 0, hence the if statement for this special case.

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.